# Vuetify3- Vue3 V-Bind not working as expected

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vuetify.js

Sorry for writing the code here, without using code snnipet, but I wasn't able to make it work.

I'm developing some generic components for a project. With that in mind I've used a property extraction strategy according to this [post](https://logaretm.com/blog/generic-type-components-with-composition-api/)

So I've created an type

```js
export declare type ExtractComponentProperties<TComponent> = TComponent extends new () => { $props: infer P }
    ? P
    : never;
```

Some interfaces to expose **properties** and **emits**

```js
import { Nullable } from '@/types/nullable';
import type { ExtractComponentProperties } from '@/types/component/properties/extract';
import type { ExtractComponentEmits } from '@/types/component/emits/extract';
export interface IComponentExtendedProperties<T> {
    properties?: ExtractComponentProperties<T>;
}
export interface IComponentProperties {
    [key: string]: unknown;
}
export interface IModelValueComponentProperties<T> extends IComponentProperties {
    modelValue?: T | Nullable<T>;
}

export interface IComponentExtendedEmits<T> {
    emits?: ExtractComponentEmits<T>;
}
```

Alson created some interfaces that are responsible exposing the extracted values

```js
import { IComponentExtendedProperties } from '@/types/component/properties';
import { IComponentExtendedEmits } from '@/types/component/emits';

export interface IPropertiesBinder<T> extends IComponentExtendedProperties<T> {}
export interface IEmitsBinder<T> extends IComponentExtendedEmits<T> {}
export interface IPropertiesEmitsBinder<T> extends IPropertiesBinder<T>, IEmitsBinder<T> {}
```

Then I've created a specific Interface foreach component that implements ExtractComponentProperties

```js
import { VMenu } from 'vuetify/lib/components/VMenu/index';
import { VBtn } from 'vuetify/lib/components/VBtn/index';
import { VList } from 'vuetify/lib/components/VList/index';
import { IPropertiesEmitsBinder,IPropertiesBinder } from '@/types/component/binder';
export interface IButton extends IPropertiesEmitsBinder<typeof VBtn> {
    text?: string;
}


export interface IMenu extends IComponentExtendedProperties<typeof VMenu> {}
export interface IList extends IPropertiesBinder<typeof VList> {
    items: IListItem[];
}
export interface IListItem extends IPropertiesEmitsBinder<typeof VListItem> {
    id: string;
    title?: string;
}
```

Then I've created ButtonDropdown.vue sfc component

```js
<template>
    <VMenu v-bind="useMenuBinder(componentProperties.menu)">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
            <slot name="activator" :props="props">
                <VBtn v-bind="useButtonBinder(componentProperties.button, props)">
                    {{ componentProperties.button?.text }}
                    <VIcon v-if="componentProperties.button?.properties?.icon" class="ml-2">
                        {{ componentProperties.button.properties.icon }}
                    </VIcon>
                </VBtn>
            </slot>
        </template>
        <VList v-bind="useListBinder(componentProperties.list)">
            <slot>
                <VListItem
                    v-for="(item, index) in availableItems"
                    :key="index"
                    :value="item"
                    v-bind="useListItemBinder(item)"
                >
                    <VListItemTitle v-if="item.title">{{ item.title }}</VListItemTitle>
                </VListItem>
            </slot>
        </VList>
    </VMenu>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { IMenu } from '@/types/component/menu';
import { IList } from '@/types/component/list';
import { IListItem } from '@/types/component/list/item';
import { IButton } from '@/types/component/button';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
export interface ButtonDropdownComponentProperties {
    menu?: IMenu;
    button?: IButton;
    list?: IList;
    items?: IListItem[];
}
const componentProperties = withDefaults(defineProps<ButtonDropdownComponentProperties>(), {
    button: () => ({
        properties: {
            icon: 'mdi-chevron-down',
            color: 'transparent',
            size: 'small',
            elevation: 0,
        },
        text: { key: 'buttons.dropdown' },
    }),
    menu: () => ({
        properties: {
            maxWidth: '300px',
            closeOnContentClick: true,
        },
    }),
    list: () => ({
        items: [{ id: generateId(), title: 'Example Text'  }],
        properties: {
            minWidth: '200vw',
            maxWidth: 'auto',
        },
    }),
});
const availableItems = computed(() => componentProperties.list?.items ?? []);
function generateId(): string {
    return uuidv4();
}
</script>
```

Now when i try to call this component

```js
<template>
    <ButtonDropdown
        :button="{ text: 'Locale', properties: { icon: 'mdi-translate', elevation: '0' } }"
    >
        <VListItem v-for="(locale, index) in availableLocales">
            {{ locale.text }}
        </VListItem>
    </ButtonDropdown>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
export interface ILocale {
    locale: string;
    text: string;
};
const localeStore = useLocaleStore();
const availableLocales = computed(() => [{locale:'en',text:'English'},{locale:'pt',text:'Portuguese'}]);
const locale = ref<ILocale>({locale:'en',text:'English'});
</script>
```

Also I've created a composable to help binding the props:

```js
import { IList } from '@/types/component/list';
import { IMenu } from '@/types/component/menu';
import { IButton } from '@/types/component/button';
import { IListItem } from '@/types/component/list/item';

export function useBinder() {
    return {
        useMenuBinder,
        useListItemBinder,
        useListBinder,
        useButtonBinder,
    };
}

export function useMenuBinder(item: IMenu): any {
    return { props: item.properties };
}
export function useListItemBinder(item: IListItem) {
    return { props: item.properties, emits: item.emits };
}
export function useListBinder(item: IList) {
    return { props: item.properties };
}
export function useButtonBinder(item: IButton, options?: any) {
    return { props: { ...item.properties }, ...options };
}
```

As you can see I've passed the elevation property as '0' but its not respecting it;

But If I go directly to the DropdownButton and set `:elevation="componentProperties.button.properties?.elevation"` it works

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found out what was happening

Looking into developer tools i noticed that the bind wasn't right
[image]

To summarize it:

The problem was that i was binding an object with props, which doesn't exists

```js
export function useButtonBinder(item: IButton, options?: any) {
    return { props: { ...item.properties }, ...options };
}
```

The right way to do this is:

```js
export function useButtonBinder(item: IButton, options?: any) {
    return {  ...item.properties , ...options };
}
```

This way the properties will be assigned to the correct values